# How to replace participant IDs with the score of the ID-holder on another variable

Tags: r, replace

I have a dataset with multiple peer nomination variables (PN), in which values are participant IDs. I need to replace the IDs under PN1-PN3 with the score of the ID-holder on another variable (VA).

Example: I have:

```
  ID PN1 PN2 PN3 VA
    ID PN1  PN2  PN3 VA
1    1   2    3 5678  7
2    2   1    3   NA  0
3    3   1    2  400  1
4  400   3 5678   NA  3
5 5678   2  400   NA  0
```

I need:

```
  ID PN1 PN2 PN3 VA
1  1   0   1   0  7
2  2   7   1  NA  0
3  3   7   0   3  1
4 400  1   0  NA  3
5 5678 0   3  NA  0
```

(So for all peer-nomination variables, every 1 should be replaced by 7, because the participant with the ID 1 has a score of 7 on "VA"; every 2 should be replaced by 0; every 3 should be replaced by 1; etc.)

Data:

```
df <- data.frame(ID = c(1, 2, 3, 400, 5678),
                 PN1 = c(2, 1, 1, 3, 2),
                 PN2 = c(3, 3, 2, 5678, 400),
                 PN3 = c(5678, NA, 400, NA, NA),
                 VA = c(7, 0, 1, 3, 0))
```

Hope that someone can help! Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: Hi - I am not totally sure how you go from your input to expected output. Could you clarify it please? Thanks.

Comment: @user438383 It looks like If a 1 appears in PN1, PN2, PN3, then that 1 would be replaced by the value in row 1 of VA(7). If a 3 appears, then you would replace the value with the 3rd value in VA (1)... etc.

Comment: Hey, I edited the question - hope it is clear now!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an approach using `match`. The value in `VA` is returned where the current value equals the value in `ID`.

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(ID = c(1, 2, 3, 400, 5678),
                 PN1 = c(2, 1, 1, 3, 2),
                 PN2 = c(3, 3, 2, 5678, 400),
                 PN3 = c(5678, NA, 400, NA, NA),
                 VA = c(7, 0, 1, 3, 0))

df %>% 
  mutate(
    across(
      starts_with("PN"),~VA[match(., ID)]
    )
  )
#>     ID PN1 PN2 PN3 VA
#> 1    1   0   1   0  7
#> 2    2   7   1  NA  0
#> 3    3   7   0   3  1
#> 4  400   1   0  NA  3
#> 5 5678   0   3  NA  0
```

<sup>Created on 2021-08-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Hey! Thanks! However, this won't work for my data, since there are missings among the IDs, so not every ID is equal to it's row number. Any idea?

Comment: I am confused. If an ID under the columns that start with `PN` is `NA`, then my approach will simply return an `NA`. Is that not what you wanted? @StefanieRichters

Comment: Since the IDs look more like c(1,2, 54, 100, 34787) in the original dataset, I am afraid this won't work without using the `ID` variable...

Comment: Can you also update your expected output?

Comment: @StefanieRichters -- Pretty interesting problem. I am trying to come up with a solution for you. Does my latest edit help? Also, it would help to update the `ID` column in your expected output since they don't align with the values in your initial dataset.

Answer (score 0):

We may also do this with a named vector

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
    mutate(across(starts_with('PN'), ~ setNames(VA, ID)[as.character(.)]))
    ID PN1 PN2 PN3 VA
1    1   0   1   0  7
2    2   7   1  NA  0
3    3   7   0   3  1
4  400   1   0  NA  3
5 5678   0   3  NA  0
```